# Difference between unity and ubuntu-unity-desktop?

Tags: unity, desktop-environments

There are two packages in ubuntu 20.04 `unity` and `ubuntu-unity-desktop`. Which one should I use to install Unity DE in my system and what is the difference between them?

Comment: Why would you take a brand new OS which was just released 3 days ago, and downgrade it with Unity? Try GNOME, give it a chance, and you'll probably be fine with it.

Comment: I use unity. It just works for me so I assume it works for CodeDexter

Comment: @TheBuntuNewb Except that GNOME is the future... and Unity is WAY in the past.

Comment: Unity is an upgrade, it makes 20.04 more usable.

Comment: It’s just a matter of personal preference

Comment: @mikewhatever It's not an upgrade. It's a 16.xx/17.xx DE, and will never be used again. Embrace GNOME Shell, and you'll probably get used to it. It's not that different than Unity. It's even got a dock!

Comment: I’ll use it till I can’t maintain it anymore. I also messed up my displays with gnome, and I can’t do that in unity

Comment: @heynnema It is an upgrade to me, and thank you for suggestions, but no thank you. I've never told anyone to use Unity over Gnome, and that should do.

Comment: @heynnema Unity is the best DE I have ever seen in my life. Gnome is also good. But not as good as Unity. Gnome is heavy and UI doesn't match with Ubuntu.

Comment: It's really sad too see **all** comments here are either suggesting OP to try another DE or defending his choice, and **none** actually helping in his question. _"What's the difference between Coke Zero and Diet Coke?" - "Try Pepsi instead!"_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`unity`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/unity) is a single package.

The [`ubuntu-unity-desktop`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/ubuntu-unity-desktop) is a [meta](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/ubuntu-unity-meta)-package. The `unity` is one of the its dependencies.

The difference would be features. You will get more features and applications with second package. It will install for example Nautilus and LightDM greeter. See complete list in the links above.

So I would recommend to install the meta package with

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

Comment: Isn't `nautilus` already part of the default (Gnome) `ubuntu-desktop`? Or does the `ubuntu-unity-desktop` metapackage pulls a customized version?

Comment: I believe a better phrasing would be along the lines of _"`unity` package is the "core" DE ("single package" does not say much), and `ubuntu-unity-desktop` is a meta-package that installs not only `unity` but also several other components and tools that better integrate with Unity than the ones from Gnome Shell, such as LightDM and Unity Greeter, Unity Settings, Notify OSD, and so on. It also installs Nautilus and other common Gnome Shell tools for those installing Unity in flavors Kubuntu, Lubuntu, etc ..."_